# Change status of useTaobaoRegistry to false

Tags: vue.js, npm

I need to change the status of `useTaobaoRegistry` to `false` but I don't know how.

```
{
  "useTaobaoRegistry": true,
  "presets": {
    "default": {
      "useConfigFiles": false,
      "plugins": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": {},
        "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": {},
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": {
          "historyMode": true
        },
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": {},
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": {
          "config": "standard",
          "lintOn": [
            "save"
          ]
        },
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": {}
      },
      "cssPreprocessor": "dart-sass"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried doing `vue config -e` but it only showed :

```
Could not open .vuerc in the editor.

Unable to open '/home/prabin/.vuerc' null
Try setting the EDITOR env variable. More info: https://github.com/yyx990803/launch-editor
```

I visited the site but I understood nothing.
Any help would be nice !

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have had your answer till now, but there is no concrete answer answer anywhere, specially for windows user. So, it will be helpful for future stackflowers.

#### Problem

You are getting the problem because there is no Default App to open such type of file extension. For example, we have Chrome, Firefox, IE for .HTML file extensions but the `.vuerc` file extension is not associated with any default app.

#### Solution

To make this work, first of all, you need to locate the file which is in your default user directory.

In windows `C:\Users\{Username-Path}`. Scroll down below, you will see `.vuerc` file. Double click on it and set you editor as Default App to open and open it.

After that, when you run, `vue config --edit` in terminal, the file will be opened in your predefined Editor. From there, you can make your desired changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change this `"useTaobaoRegistry": false` in  `~/.vuerc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Right clic on the .vuerc file and choose : Open with > an ["in-the-list" editor](https://github.com/yyx990803/launch-editor#supported-editors)

Hope this will help you ;)